# MySQL: WHERE IN with JOIN inside

Tags: mysql

I have 3 SQL tables.

**Games** wo_tenis_partidos

[image]

**Selections** wo_tenis_pronosticos

[image]

**Quotas** wo_tenis_cuotas_ha2

[image]

I need to get all rows with two conditions:

**Condition 1:** where CUOTA1 >= CUOTAMIN1 **or** CUOTA2 >= CUOTAMIN2

**Condition 2:** Add all rows with same ID_PARTIDO that appeared in Condition 1

The condition 1 is easy:

```
SELECT *               
FROM wo_tenis_partidos a
INNER JOIN wo_tenis_cuotas_ha2 c ON c.id_partido = a.id
INNER JOIN wo_tenis_pronosticos p ON p.id_partido = a.id
WHERE
a.resultado IS NULL 
AND (c.cuota1 >= p.cuotamin1 OR c.cuota2 >= p.cuotamin2)
```

But to add the condiciton 2 I need to do this:

```
SELECT *               
FROM wo_tenis_partidos a
INNER JOIN wo_tenis_cuotas_ha2 c ON c.id_partido = a.id
INNER JOIN wo_tenis_pronosticos p ON p.id_partido = a.id
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT a.id                 
    FROM wo_tenis_partidos a
    INNER JOIN wo_tenis_cuotas_ha2 c ON c.id_partido = a.id
    INNER JOIN wo_tenis_pronosticos p ON p.id_partido = a.id    
    AND a.resultado IS NULL 
    AND (c.cuota1 >= p.cuotamin1 OR c.cuota2 >= p.cuotamin2)                        
)
```

It's the correct way? there is another more optimized alternative?

Comment: are you getting desired output or you want optimized solution only?

Comment: Yes, I get desired output but I want to optimize my query

Answer (score 2):

No need of INNER JOIN in first query and use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` clause for better performance

```
SELECT *               
FROM wo_tenis_partidos aa
INNER JOIN wo_tenis_cuotas_ha2 c ON c.id_partido = aa.id
INNER JOIN wo_tenis_pronosticos p ON p.id_partido = aa.id
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1                 
      FROM wo_tenis_partidos a
      INNER JOIN wo_tenis_cuotas_ha2 c ON c.id_partido = a.id
      INNER JOIN wo_tenis_pronosticos p ON p.id_partido = a.id    
      AND a.resultado IS NULL 
      AND (c.cuota1 >= p.cuotamin1 OR c.cuota2 >= p.cuotamin2) 
      WHERE aa.id =a.id                        
)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. The outer entry from 'a' is overwritten by an 'a' defined in the EXISTS subclause. The currently checked extry has no effect on evaluation, so it either accepts all entries or none.

Comment: Just Updated,missing condition in exists clause Thansk

Comment: With your query I get 83 rows but the correct solution with my query is 280 rows. Also if you remove INNER JOIN in first query I lose wo_tenis_cuotas_ha2 and wo_tenis_pronosticos data to show in my PHP script like $row ['cuotamin1'] ...

Comment: Updated the script,try it

Comment: Works fine!, but in third and fouth line you need to put: aa.id

Comment: I don't sure your EXISTS query has better performance than my WHERE IN query. I try 1000 iterations in a large table and WHERE IN is 30 sg faster

Comment: EXISTS is more faster than IN operator because 'IN' operator is used to find any matches of values in column where as exists is used for boolean condition and Most important diffrence is that  IN doesn't use indexes at the time of fetching but Exist uses Index at the time of fetching.